# Find the last item in a JSON array in Postgres 9.4

Tags: json, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

We had a legacy system that attempted to keep track of all versions of data saved of a particular document. We originally stored our JSON as a string in some old version of Postgres, but recently we upgraded to Postgres 9.3 and we started using the JSON column type.

We had a column called "versions", and it held an an array, and each saved version of a particular document was stored in the array, so a query like this:

```
SELECT _data_as_json FROM measurements WHERE id = 3307551
```

returned JSON like this:

```
 {"reports": {}, "versions": [
 {"timestamp": "2014-04-28T19:12:31.567415", "user": 11327, "legacy": {}, "vd_version": 1}, 
 {"timestamp": "2014-05-12T18:03:24.417029", "user": 11331, "legacy": {"lengthmoment": {"moment": {"size": 130}, "length": {"in": 64.0}}, "comments": "", "custom": null}, "vd_version": 1}, 
 {"timestamp": "2014-05-12T21:52:50.045758", "user": 10373, "legacy": {"lengthmoment": {"moment": {"size": 130}, "length": {"in": 64.0}}, "comments": "", "custom": null}, "vd_version": 1}, 
 {"timestamp": "2014-05-14T23:34:37.797822", "user": 10380, "legacy": {"lengthmoment": {"moment": {"size": 130}, "length": {"in": 64.0}}, "comments": "", "custom": null}, "vd_version": 1}, 
 {"timestamp": "2014-07-16T14:56:38.667363", "user": 10374, "legacy": {"lengthmoment": {"moment": {"size": 130}, "length": {"in": 64.0}}, "comments": "", "custom": null}, "vd_version": 1}, 
 {"timestamp": "2014-07-16T14:57:47.341541", "user": 10374, "legacy": {"lengthmoment": {"moment": {"size": 130}, "length": {"in": 64.0}}, "comments": "", "custom": null}, "vd_version": 1}, 
 {"timestamp": "2014-07-17T16:32:09.067026", "user": 11331, "legacy": {"lengthmoment": {"moment": {"size": 130}, "length": {"in": 64.0}}, "comments": "", "custom": null}, "vd_version": 1}, 
 {"timestamp": "2014-09-11T14:35:44.436886", "user": 11331, "legacy": {"lengthmoment": {"moment": {"size": 130}, "length": {"in": 64.0}}, "comments": "", "custom": null}, "vd_version": 1}, 
 {"timestamp": "2014-10-15T14:30:50.554932", "user": 10383, "legacy": {"lengthmoment": {"moment": {"size": 130}, "length": {"in": 64.0}}, "comments": "", "custom": null}, "vd_version": 1}, 
 {"timestamp": "2014-10-29T15:36:35.183787", "user": 11331, "legacy": {"lengthmoment": {"moment": {"size": 130}, "length": {"in": 64.0}}, "comments": "", "custom": null}, "vd_version": 1}, 
 {"timestamp": "2014-11-12T22:22:03.892484", "user": 10373, "legacy": {"lengthmoment": {"moment": {"size": 130}, "length": {"in": 64.0}}, "comments": "", "custom": null}, "vd_version": 1}
 ]}
```

We (attempted to) stored the data in "versions" in chronological order, but 99% of the time, we only need the last document. In Postgres 9.3, we came up with this query to get the last item:

```
SELECT json_array_elements(_data_as_json->'versions')
FROM measurements
WHERE id = 3307551
LIMIT 1 OFFSET (SELECT json_array_length(_data_as_json->'versions') - 1 FROM measurements WHERE id = 3307551)
```

This basically works, but it is a little fragile. If we ever fail to order things correctly in the versions array, then we get back the wrong version of the document. I'm curious if there is a better way to do this? I have read that Postgres 9.4 offers more functions for dealing with JSON.

Ideally, we could do ORDER BY on the "timestamp". Is that possible?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

#### Postgres 9.5+

The job is simple now since, [quoting the manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html)

> The field/element/path extraction operators that accept integer JSON
> array subscripts all support **negative subscripting from the end of arrays**.

Bold emphasis mine. So for either `json` or `jsonb`:

```
SELECT data->'versions'->>-1
FROM   measurements m
WHERE  id = 3307551;
```

#### Postgres 9.4

You may want to use [`jsonb` instead of `json`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html). Use [`jsonb_array_elements()` or `jsonb_array_length()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE) accordingly.

There is a general approach to get the last element according to original sort order using `WITH ORDINALITY` (slightly slower without):

```sql
SELECT v.ver
FROM   measurements m
     , jsonb_array_elements(m.data->'versions') WITH ORDINALITY v(ver, ord)
WHERE  m.id = 3307551
ORDER  BY v.ord DESC
LIMIT  1;
```

Details for `WITH ORDINALITY` (and the implicit `JOIN LATERAL` in both versions):

- [PostgreSQL unnest() with element number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760419/postgresql-unnest-with-element-number/8767450#8767450)

#### Postgres 9.3

"last" according to the timestamp value:

```sql
SELECT v.ver
FROM   measurements m
     , json_array_elements(m.data->'versions') v(ver)
WHERE  m.id = 3307551
ORDER  BY  (v.ver->>'timestamp')::timestamp DESC
LIMIT  1;
```

"last" according to ordinal position in the `json` array (faster):

```sql
SELECT data->'versions'->(json_array_length(data->'versions') - 1)
FROM   measurements
WHERE  id = 3307551;
```

We need `- 1` because JSON arrays start at offset 0.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=1c3c3befec39dadcb8df986fba6aab97)*
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/97088/16)</sub>